# Can a multiclassed character have spell slots that they cannot prepare spells for?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, multi-classing

I am currently playing in a 5e game as a multiclassed Arcane Trickster 10 / Alchemist 3. According to the Artificer multiclassing rules(TCE pg. 10) and the general multiclassing rules(PHB pgs. 164 and 165) I am a 5th level caster with four 1st level spell slots, three 2nd level slots and two 3rd level slots. (Arcane Trickster 10/3 rounded down = 3. Alchemist 3/2 rounded up = 2. 3+2=5)

The ***Spells Known and Prepared*** section of the multiclassing rules(PHB pg. 164) says to prepare spells for each class separately. Since neither an Arcane Trickster 10, nor an Alchemist 3 would have 3rd level spells, does this mean that I cannot prepare 3rd level spells, even though I have the slots for it?

Comment: I’ve added the [tag:dnd-5e] tag for you since you mentioned 5e. Just keep in mind that it’s really important to use tags to identify what game you are playing when you ask questions, and the more specific the better. There are other game that have a 5th edition, so we want to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: We almost certainly have this question somewhere already, but I can’t find at the moment.

Comment: I'm a little bit tempted to reopen this. Certainly, the *information* necessary to answer this question is present in the other linked questions: but this particular question wasn't really asked elsewhere, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Gandalfmeansme I think [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110916/how-do-my-spells-work-when-multi-classing-ranger-and-druid) is an exact dupe, and the others are close enough.